# Make a wrapper appear as the function it wraps in help()

Tags: python, wrapper, docstring, pydoc

I'm using python **2.4** unfortunately (not by choice) so none of the wonderful things added in 2.5 (such as functools) can help me

I want to wrap a function, but make it so that when you do help(wrapper) it appears to be the function that it wraps

I've partially achieved this by doing

```
def a():
    """a's docstring"""
    pass

def wrapper():
    a() 
wrapper.func_name = a.func_name #or should this use __name__ ?
wrapper.func_doc = a.func_doc #or should this use __doc__ ?
```

Now doing `help(wrapper)` displays `a` for the function name and `a`'s docstring.  Besides feeling hacky, this doesn't cover the function parameters in a case such as:

```
def b(x, y, z): 
    return a+b+c #or whatever

def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    #do something with the arguments
    return b(*args **kwargs)
```

`help(wrapper)` causes this to appear as `b(*args, **kwargs)` which isn't what I want, obviously.   There doesn't seem to be any attribute in `dir(a)` that can help me unless it's nested somewhere.

---

EDIT:
if you can use pypi, look at the decorator module which helps with this.

Comment: Yes, you should use `__name__` and `__doc__`.

Comment: by the way, anyone reading this.  I think Decorator.decorator can fix this, too bad I'm using python2.4 -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Note that it *doesn't* fake out the argument specification. You probably could do that (using `inspect.getargspec` to work out the argument specification of `foo` and then hacking `bar`), but it's not conventional.

---

EDIT: Since you're using Python 2.4, you'll have to re-implement the functionality of `functools.wraps`. Fortunately it is actually pretty simple; it just copies over the attributes `__module__`, `__name__` and `__doc__`, and then updates the wrapper's `__dict__` with the wrapped function's `__dict__`. So you could do:

```
WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS = ('__module__', '__name__', '__doc__')
WRAPPER_UPDATES = ('__dict__',)

def update_wrapper(wrapper,
                   wrapped,
                   assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
                   updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):
    for attr in assigned:
        setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
    for attr in updated:
        getattr(wrapper, attr).update(getattr(wrapped, attr, {}))
    # Return the wrapper so this can be used as a decorator via partial()
    return wrapper

def wraps(wrapped,
          assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
          updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):
    return partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped,
                   assigned=assigned, updated=updated)
```

(FYI this is the actual source code of `functools.wraps`.)

Comment: This would be alright if I didn't have to use python2.4 haha.  I should've mentioned that

Comment: @xhainingx you'll have to look at the source code for `wraps`, then, and re-implement it yourself. Or, much better, upgrade to a non-obsolete Python version.

Comment: I would gladly do that if it were up to me.  Legacy systems, dude

Comment: The `functools` source code is at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5ef49659935f/Lib/functools.py if you want to make your own implementation.

Comment: So that with the source for `partial` will do the first part, but it doesn't look like that'll cover the arguments.  Which is still my main issue.

Comment: @xhainingx my point is that many people write wrappers, and the convention is that one doesn't copy over the argument specification. If you know exactly what arguments the wrapper should date, you could just make them the same as the wrapped function. And if you don't, surely you _shouldn't_ fake out the argspec?

Comment: It make sense in the context of what I'm doing.  I'm creating wrappers on the fly each time there is an attempt to use a function in a module.  All of the functions are generators that trace a shape.  The distance between two points on the shape depends on the type of object following that pattern.
It is a multithreaded program, where each type of object has its position updated at different frequencies.  But the frequency should be invisible to someone creating a generator.  So if the speed is given as 12m/s but it's update frequency is 4hz, the generator needs 12/4 as it's speed parameter.

Comment: Nice answer , Helped me find a way to reach the docstring of the real function and not the wrapper